# file_get_contents failed to load a webpage

Tags: php

I have the [url](http://%20$contents%20=%20file_get_contents($_POST['url']);) that I want to read the content of. The `file_get_contents()` says it failed to load the stream.. what is wrong with this url?

```
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://https://support.office.com/en-
us/article/Combine-the-results-of-seve…select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-
3d4fd525-e5ac-4245-99b3-4f4b66cdb2a1): failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Comment: Your link is incorrect. WHat is your error message?

Comment: @kurt I have updated the question

Comment: ok.. I got it.. I am trying to append extra `http://` to it... some incorret prefixing.. :(

Comment: @Kitler... Why are you all up against me?? Such bad behavior and mocking in chat  room now down voting for the question.. I know its bad but I can't delete it now because it has anwers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url in incorrect.Use either Http or Https depending on what is required.

```
https://support.office.com/en-
us/article/Combine-the-results-of-seve…select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-

or

http://support.office.com/en-
us/article/Combine-the-results-of-seve…select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-
```

Answer (score 2):

Your url is wrong, you are using "http://" twice in the url, please replace "http://https://" with "http://".

Comment: Yes figured it out.. some error with regex I have employed to fix the urls.. I think..